# \hline initialises first cell

Tags: tables

\hline initialises the first cell with being empty. This results in having the vertical lines being draw.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx} %Used for importing grapics
\usepackage{bookmark} %This will create the digitale bookmarks of the resulting pdf
\usepackage[top=1.25in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry} % setting the margins of the paper


\newcounter{versionnumber}

\newcommand{\version}[3]{
v.\theversionnumber .0 &
#1 &        % parameter 1
#2 &        % parameter 2
#3 \\       % parameter 3
\hline      %draw line under each version

\stepcounter{versionnumber}
}

\newenvironment{changelist}
{ \begin{tabular}{
    |  m{0.10\textwidth}        % set static column width
    || m{0.28\textwidth}
    |  m{0.12\textwidth}
    |  m{0.40\textwidth} | }
\hline
\textbf{Version}    &
\textbf{Author}     &
\textbf{Date}       &
\textbf{Change log} \\
\hline      % Draw horizontal line under column titels
& & & \\    % Leave some whitespace
}
{ \end{tabular} }


\begin{document}
\setcounter{versionnumber}{1}

\begin{changelist}
\version{A name}{A date}{some explanation}
\end{changelist}

\end{document}
```

Can someone help me out?
I have no idea why the vertical line of the first cell of the second row are being drawn.
When giving with a value. This value gets put on the first cell and the same problem occurst with the cell next to it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\hline` does *not* initialize the first cell. The definition of `\hline` is (from `latex.ltx`):

```
\def\hline{%
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet
   \reserved@a\@xhline
}
\def\@xhline{%
  \ifx\reserved@a\hline
    \vskip\doublerulesep
    \vskip-\arrayrulewidth
  \fi
  \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
}
```

A lot of "voodoo", but the important part is, that the line is drawn inside `\noalign`.

The TeX primitive `\noalign` can be used before a new table row starts and it
takes vertical mode material that is put at this place without considering alignment.

Also your cell is *not empty*, it contains `\stepcounter{versionnumber}`, enough to start a new cell in a new row. Again `\noalign` can be used to "hide" the `\stepcounter` assignment, because counter assignments are global in LaTeX:

```
\hline
\noalign{\stepcounter{versionnumber}%
```

Full example (with package `array` that is needed for column specifier `m`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{array} % provides column specifier "m"
\usepackage{graphicx} % Used for importing grapics
\usepackage{bookmark} % This will create the digitale bookmarks of the resulting pdf
\usepackage[top=1.25in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry} % setting the margins of the paper


\newcounter{versionnumber}

\newcommand{\version}[3]{
v.\theversionnumber .0 &
#1 &        % parameter 1
#2 &        % parameter 2
#3 \\       % parameter 3
\hline      % draw line under each version
\noalign{\stepcounter{versionnumber}}%
}

\newenvironment{changelist}
{ \begin{tabular}{
    |  m{0.10\textwidth}        % set static column width
    || m{0.28\textwidth}
    |  m{0.12\textwidth}
    |  m{0.40\textwidth} | }
\hline
\textbf{Version}    &
\textbf{Author}     &
\textbf{Date}       &
\textbf{Change log} \\
\hline      % Draw horizontal line under column titels
& & & \\    % Leave some whitespace
}
{ \end{tabular} }


\begin{document}
\setcounter{versionnumber}{1}

\begin{changelist}
\version{A name}{A date}{some explanation}
\end{changelist}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't think that stepcounter wouls return a void that latex would display leaving and in this case placing it in that cell